# Suppress Mypy notes

Tags: python, mypy

I'm getting a ton of "notes" from Mypy output of the form:

```
note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
```

Even explicitly setting `check_untyped_defs = false` in my `pyproject.toml` doesn't help.

How can I suppress these notes?

Comment: Is setting `check_untyped_defs` to `true`, in your case, possible?

Comment: Just set `disable_error_code = annotation-unchecked` in config file to disable this message.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks!  Adding `disable_error_code = "annotation-unchecked"` indeed solved it!

Comment: should I added into `setup.cfg` file?

Comment: @alper whatever config you are using (might also be `pyproject.toml / [tool.mypy]` section)

Comment: @smido Thanks I will try it, seems like it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with `--disable-error-code "annotation-unchecked"`

Except for getting rid of tons of terminal lines, it might needed if you are using 'junit' style reports and your CI/Jenkins will mark this build as failure, even though the mypy command itself returns with 0 (Success: no issues found)